# how to fetch subcollection's data in firestore?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

I have built a webapp using node express to backend and for frontend I used Reactjs .
In firestore database has a "**users**" collection in there have many documents for every users. For each document have fields and have subcollections.

**1st view**
[image]

**2nd view (in a subcollection view)**
[image]
this is the sample database like my real database structure .**I want fetch all users(inside  the users table documents) andalso with subcollections fields.**

**For every users have same subcollections.(Like as this image user have 4 subcollections andaslo another user also have that same subcollections.)**

For this I write the code like this.

**model class**

```
    class Users {
    constructor(id,name,email,provider,firstWord,leda,age,birthday,district,gender,familyChildren,fatherEducation,monthlyIncome,motherEducation,whichChild,awaSE,awaUN,kathakaraaSE,kathakaraaSE,kathakaraaUN) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
            this.provider = provider; 

            this.email = firstWord;
            this.email = leda;
           
            this.age = age;
            this.birthday = birthday; 
            this.district = district; 
            this.gender = gender; 

            this.familyChildren = familyChildren;
            this.fatherEducation = fatherEducation;
            this.monthlyIncome = monthlyIncome;
            this.motherEducation = motherEducation; 
            this.whichChild = whichChild;
            
            this.awaSE = awaSE; 
            this.awaUN = awaUN; 
            this.kathakaraaSE = kathakaraaSE; 
            this.kathakaraaUN = kathakaraaUN; 
           
      
    }
}
module.exports = Users;
```

**controller**

```
'use strict';

const firebase = require('../db');
const Users = require('../models/users');
const firestore = firebase.firestore();

const getAllUsers = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const users = await firestore.collection('users');
        const data = await users.get();
        const userArray = [];
        if(data.empty) {
            res.status(404).send('No user  found');
        }else {
            data.forEach(doc => {
                const users = new Users(
                    doc.id,
                    doc.data().name,
                    doc.data().email,
                    doc.data().provider,
                    doc.data().firstWord,
                    doc.data().leda,
                    doc.data().age,
                    doc.data().birthday,
                    doc.data().district,
                    doc.data().gender,
                    doc.data().familyChildren,
                    doc.data().fatherEducation,
                    doc.data().monthlyIncome,
                    doc.data().motherEducation,
                    doc.data().whichChild,
                    doc.data().awaSE,
                    doc.data().awaUN,
                    doc.data().kathakaraaSE,
                    doc.data().kathakaraaUN,
                    
                );
                userArray.push(users);
            });
            res.send(userArray);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error.message);
    }
}


module.exports = {

    getAllUsers,

}
```

**router class**

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const { getAllUsers } = require('../controllers/userscontroller.js')
 


router.get('/AllUsers', getAllUsers);


 
module.exports = router;
```

**model class image**

[image]

1.users collection fields
2.childGrow collection fields
3.childPrivateDetails collection fields
4.familyDetails collection fields
5.wenath collection fields

but out put is

[image]
in there not display other collections  fields.

**How I do that using node express?**

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
const getAllUsers = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const users = await getFirestore().collection('users');
    const data = await users.get();
    const userArray = [];
    if (data.empty) {
      res.status(404).send('No user  found');
    } else {
      for (let doc of data.docs) {
        let firstSubCollectionData = await getFirestore().collection('users').doc(doc.id).collection('firstSubCollection').get();
        let secondSubCollectionData = await getFirestore().collection('users').doc(doc.id).collection('secondSubCollectionData').get();
        let thirdSubCollectionData = await getFirestore().collection('users').doc(doc.id).collection('thirdSubCollectionData').get();
        let forthSubCollectionData = await getFirestore().collection('users').doc(doc.id).collection('forthSubCollectionData').get();
        // construct your object here
        // add it to list
      }
      res.send(userArray);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error.message);
  }
}
```

**BUT**

sub-collections can be potentially a list of values. If not I think you have to redesign your data model.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. what is "firstSubCollectionData " is this field of first subcollection

Comment: Not worked bro..

Comment: firstSubCollectionData Is the list of docs in the sub-collection. Try to log .data() and see what is in the values inside